# brew install doesn't link python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7

I'm having trouble linking python3 and making python3 the default python.

`MacOS 10.13.6`

Here's what I did:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.0
$ xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2349.
$ brew install python
...

Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin
...
```

It doesn't work. `python` is still 2.*

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.0
$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
$ pip3 --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

So I did:

```
$ brew link python3
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
$ brew install python3
...

Warning: python 3.7.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.7.0, run `brew reinstall python`
$ brew reinstall python
```

Also doesn't work

```
$ brew link python3
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.0
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I presume you mean that you want the command `python` to start the **Python3** interpreter, and `pip` to start `pip3`.

The clue is in the message:

> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
>   `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
>     /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

That means... *"if you want the command `python` to start `python3` and `pip` to start `pip3`, you need to put `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` at the start of your PATH."*

So, in your login script (`$HOME/.profile` or similar), you need to put:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

Then log out and log back in for it to take effect.

---

As an aside, `brew link python3` only means... *"create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin/python3` that points to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/python3`"*.

You can see that link, and where it points to, with:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark, I was following [this guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install/osx/), your answer makes a lot more sense. I'll try again and mark your answer as correct very soon.

Comment: Was looking for this, thanks! Also, for someone who's looking for it: If you're running zsh, add the `export` statement to your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Meh, that's what I expect brew should do for me /

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had tried everything except for the logout. I saw your solution and tried. Works now

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with brew 4.0.19 and python 3.11 on macOS 13.3.1—but this answer doesn't work (the "Unversioned symlinks..." message doesn't show after `brew install python` and adding the `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` to my `PATH` doesn't help in any case—that dir doesn't exist on my system.)

Comment: @RobertAtkins Did you run `brew info python` ? Because if I run that on my system, I get the message about unversioned links. And note that **homebrew** now makes the links in `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin` rather than `usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` because it has changed in the 5 years since I wrote this answer.

Comment: Aha! Yes, that was the clue—I guessed the location might have changed as part of the brew update for m1, adding `/opt/homebrew/opt/python/libexec/bin` to my path gets me what I wanted (without the `@3.11`, the bare `.../python/libexec/bin`  is itself a link to the latest version.)

Why doesn't `brew` do all this for me, _grumble_.

Answer (score 1):

At least for python 3.6 the selected answer appears to be incorrect.
It may depend on whether you have multiple python versions brew installed.
In my case i have 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9.
so, you

```
brew unlink python@3.9
brew link python@3.6
```

after which:

- there is no entry /usr/local/opt/python
- there is no entry /usr/local/bin/python3

`brew link python3` links the most recent python install (3.9 in my case) regardless of the brew link python@3.6 issued earlier so it is not useful.

There is an entry /usr/local/bin/python3.6 and there is a symbolic link
/usr/local/bin/python -> python3 but NO /usr/local/bin/python3 entry.

so if you

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.6 python3
```

you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed `python` via brew and had to follow different steps:

```
brew install python
```

Later, I needed the path to add to my $PATH as `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH` wasn't working for me.

I ran:

```
brew info python
```

Got this:

```
Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin
```

And then added this to my `.zshrc` file

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

With these steps, you have made Python 3.11 the default version on your Mac. You can now use python to refer to Python 3.11 in your terminal.

For more details, I shared the entire process in [Python not found on MacOS](https://ahmadawais.com/python-not-found-on-macos-install-python-with-brew-fix-path/). I hope this helps.

Make sure to reload your terminal, a fancy way to do that is by running:

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

Comment: You can also take out the `@3.11` from the path in your `.zshrc` file example to have it point to whatever the latest version is. This way you won't have to remember to update your `.zshrc` when you install the next version of python